# This code has a function call with no parameters - working in C# but NOT VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, console-application, mouse-hook

I'm trying to use [this code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx?), which is in C#, in VB.NET. The code's purpose is to read the mouse coordinates and output them when you click the mouse button, using a Console application. Yes, I realise this is a stupid use of a Console application, but it may be necessary for a project I want to undertake. I've managed to make it work in C#, but in VB.NET I get an error in this area:

```
Private Shared _proc As LowLevelMouseProc = HookCallback()
```

The C# line is:

```
private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
```

The HookCallback function has three parameters, I've included the code below:

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 &&
                MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

For some reason in the C# code, it calls the HookCallback function with no parameters listed and this is absolutely fine. In VB.NET, this doesn't work, as I would expect. My question is: how can I make this work in VB.NET? I'm new to C#, otherwise I would use the C# code.

Comment: Your VB declaration has `()` at the end.. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I wish, it returns the same error with and without the brackets. I don't believe VB.NET is too fussy about the inclusion of brackets when you're making a function call with no parameters.

Comment: The C# code isn't calling that method, it's creating a delegate that points to that function.  In VB you're trying to actually call the function, hence the problems.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y72ewk2b.aspx

Comment: VB requires the AddressOf keyword.  And no, you cannot make this hook work in a console mode app.  It requires a message loop, Application.Run().

Comment: @HansPassant - There's no way whatsoever that this will work? Are you sure? And what do you mean by a message loop?

Comment: Strange.  If you never heard of a message loop before then why would you ask me if I'm sure?  It only matters that you are sure that you can make it work.  You're bound to learn something new.

Comment: Well, your knowledge is superior to mine - if you think it can't work, I have to take your word for it. I'm not sure that I can make it work - I know very little about the actual functioning of this code.

Comment: I'm just trying to get this code to the point where it returns integer coordinates telling me where the mouse is clicking. I can probably work out the rest from there.

Comment: Never mind, I've got it working, thanks to your original suggestion. My only problem was that I forgot to call the Main sub in the class from the Main sub outside of the class.